# Slug field followed by url

Tags: django, django-urls, url

I just started Django and Python, so Im still new to this..
This is my urls.py:

```
url(r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','person_detail'),
url(r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/$','person_delete'),
```

The problem is that when I try to do to the url: slug/delete/ it's looking for that whole part slug/delete/ as the slug. When i remove the $ in the 1st url it does not go to the person_delete view, but goes to the person_detail view, ignoring the /delete/ part
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding a leading `^`:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','person_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/$','person_delete'),
```

That said, without the leading `^` I'd expect `foo/delete/` to get you to the `person_detail` view with `slug` as `delete`, rather than `foo/delete`.

Comment: When - is the first character of a character class, it does not denote a range, but is instead a literal -.

Comment: @AKX - thanks. Edited with what I *think* might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
url(r'(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$','person_detail'),
url(r'(?P<slug>[^/]+)/delete/$','person_delete'),
```

to make sure the slug can not contain a slash? You could also try having the rules in the opposite order, to try have Django match /.../delete/ first.

Comment: `[-\w]+` won't match a `/`, either. `\w` is a synonym for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, and `-` (at the beginning of end of a set) is, well, a dash.

Answer (score 1):

Note that slug fields might also include digits (not just letters and the dash), so you want to alter it to say something like:

```
SLUG = '(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)'

url(r'^'+SLUG+'/delete$', delete_method, {}, 'delete_url_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/$','person_delete'),
url(r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/','person_detail'),
```

Url order is important in such cases, because url dispacher using first match. Common url should be last.

Comment: Not in this case, since the OP ended his URLs with the `$` sign, which matches the end of the string.

Comment: Oops.. i misunderstood question - i think that he delete $ from first url, that caused all troubles.